# Where do I find llvm for compiling Qt documentation

Tags: compiling, environment-variables, qt, 20.10, clang

> Note: To build qdoc and Qt documentation in future you should set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR environment >variable pointing to directory where LLVM is installed (it should be top level directory, the >configuration scripts use relative path tracing from this directory). For example, in Linux with >LLVM installed in isolated directory (/usr/llvm), at a bash prompt:
>
> $ export LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/llvm

I am running Kubuntu 20.10 and I have no `/usr/llvm` directory. The closest I have is, `/usr/include/llvm-11/llvm/` << is that right?

Is it supposed to be there, and if not where can I find it now?

Comment: All Qt5 stuff is already packaged - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/groovy/qttools-opensource-src . And LLVM too - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=llvm&mode=exactfilename&suite=groovy&arch=any . What is your final idea?

Answer (score 1):

A note in the documentation states that debian users will find the directory here:

> Debian allows parallel installs of `libclang-<version>-dev` in `/usr/lib/llvm-<version>` so `LLVM_INSTALL_DIR` should be `/usr/lib/llvm-<version>` to build qdoc. Not `/usr/llvm`.

https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

It applies to myself as well. I went ahead and set an environment variable of my terminal

```bsh
➜ echo $LLVM_INSTALL_DIR 
/usr/lib/llvm-11
```

And now I am able to build Qt with documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For future *Me*...

This can also be found with

```
llvm-config --prefix
```

prints e.g.: `/usr/lib/llvm-6.0`